# Writing a macro to `#[derive(strum_macros::EnumString)]` on all variants (26 of them) for my AlphabertEnum

Tags: rust, enums, macros

I am well-aware of the [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.3/) crate and its associated `EnumString` trait, with which I can "convert" a string of type `String` to an enum variant.

I have an enum named `Alphabert`, it has 26 variants.

```rust
enum Alphabert {
    A
    B
    C
// omitted
    Z
}
```

Now, having to write 26 lines of something like `#[strum(serialize = "A", serialize = "a")]` [(docs)](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.3/strum_macros/derive.EnumString.html) is quite crazy so I want to write a macro for it. The generated codes, I hope, will look like:

```
#[derive(EnumString)]
enum Alphabert {
    #[strum(serialize = "A", serialize = "a")]
    A
    #[strum(serialize = "B", serialize = "b")]
    B
// omitted
    #[strum(serialize = "Z", serialize = "z")]
    Z
}
```

Here is my attempt at writing such a macro:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! enum_impl_display_debug_enumstring {
  (pub enum $name:ident {
        $($variant:ident),*,
    }) => {
    
    #[derive(strum_macros::EnumString)]
    pub enum $name {
        // need to be able to 'cast' the token `$variant` to type `&str` and both lower and upper cases
        $(#[strum(serialize = $variant, serialize = $variant)]
        $variant),*
      }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: expected string literal
 --> src/enums.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     T,
  |     ^
```

Which is definitely because `$variant` token is not of type `&str`. The macro `stringify` converts a token to the `String` type. So I an unaware of any helper macro or mechanism I can use to convert a token `$variant` to a `&str` type.

And also, how about converting the 'resultant' `&str` type to both lower and upper cases?

**UPDATE / EDIT**
Following the update from Jmb, I updated my enum definition and it works, here it is:

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Display, EnumString)]
#[strum(serialize_all = "UPPERCASE")]
#[strum(ascii_case_insensitive)]
pub enum Alphaberts {
    A
    B
// omitted
    Z

}

fn main() {
    let a = Alphaberts::from_str("t").unwrap();
    println!("a: {}!", a); // Outputs: a: A!
```

Comment: Note that `stringify!` converts a token to a `&'static str`, not a `String`. But that doesn't help you because you need a string _literal_ not a `&str`. AFAIK what you want is impossible with `macro_rules!` macros, you would need to write a procedural macro for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strum allows you to [configure the case of the serialized variants](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/additional_attributes/index.html#attributes-on-enums). What you want can likely be accomplished with `#[strum(ascii_case_insensitive)]`:

```
#[derive(EnumString)]
#[strum(ascii_case_insensitive)]
enum Alphabert {
    A,
    B,
// omitted
    Z
}
```